# Why isn't my object private when my variable is?

Tags: javascript, private-members

I'm trying to make a object private, but not sure how to do that. As you can see the name variable is private, I can't edit it but when it comes to the object that I return, I can edit. I dont want that to be possible, though. 
I quite new to object-oriented and private methods in javascript, so could someone tell me what's right and wrong here. :) How can I solve this?
Thanks!

```
var User = function() {

  var name = 'bob';
  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }

  var otherInfo = {
    age: 20,
    human: true,
  }
  this.getOther = function() {
    return otherInfo;
  }

}

var person = new User();

var name = person.getName();
name = 'jenny';
console.log(person.getName()); // bob

var other = person.getOther();
other.age = 'wtf?';
console.log(person.getOther()); // { age: 'wtf?', human: true }
```

Comment: If you don't want changes to the return value of `person.getOther()` to change the value of `otherInfo`, then you need to return a copy of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

Primitive values such as Strings are **passed by value**. This means when you assign a String to your variable, you are setting the actual value of the String to the variable.

Objects are **passed by reference**. This means when you assign an Object to your variable, you are simply making a *reference* to the Object, not it's actual value. If you had one Object and assigned it to 6 different variables, each variable would have a *reference* to the same underlying Object.

In your example, your `getOther` method is returning a *reference* to the `otherInfo` object. So when you set the `age` property to "wtf", you are setting it on the Object that your variable refers to.

Answer (score 0):

It is happen, because in JS object passes by link - there are not coped from source object.

Just try copy object:

```
var User = function() {

  var name = 'bob';
  this.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }

  var otherInfo = {
    age: 20,
    human: true,
  }
  this.getOther = function() {
    return Object.assign({}, otherInfo);
  }

}

var person = new User();

var name = person.getName();
name = 'jenny';
console.log(person.getName()); // bob

var other = person.getOther();
other.age = 'wtf?';
console.log(person.getOther()); // { age: 20, human: true }
```

Comment: This doesn't truly copy the object. Instead it uses `this.otherInfo` as the prototype for the new object.

Comment: Thank you, I'v fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You also declare `var name` twice.

When you `var person = new User();` a `var name` is declared within the scope of the User function.

When you `var name = person.getName();` you are declaring a variable with the same name outside the scope of the User function.

So, when you `name = 'Jenny';` the interpreter associates this string the `name` variable outside the scope of User.

In general, it is a bad idea to use such variables with common names (name, title, id, ...) as global variables. I would refer to the object attributes with `this.` and define `setters` as well as `getters`. You can also ignore the `setters` and refer to the User attributes with `person.`, like this:

```
function User() {
  this.name = 'bob';
  this.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
  }

  this.otherInfo = {
    age: 20,
    human: true,
  }
  this.getOther = function() {
    return this.otherInfo;
  }

}

var person = new User();

console.log(person.getName()); // bob
person.name = 'jenny';
console.log(person.getName()); // jenny

console.log(person.getOther(); // { age: 20, human: true }
person.otherInfo.age = 'wtf?';
console.log(person.getOther()); // { age: 'wtf?', human: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have “private” things in object scope in Javascript. The only way to hide things from the outside is with a function scope, like you did with `name` (a local variable in the function `User`).

To return an object with the same content every time, you could make the object inside the function. Like this, for instance:

```
this.getOther = function() {
    var otherInfo = {
        age: 20,
        human: true,
    }
    return otherInfo;
}
```

Or just:

```
this.getOther = function() {
    return {
        age: 20,
        human: true,
    };
}
```

In both cases, you will be creating a new object with every call.